# xpages categorized column

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

A lotus notes application is using a view with a column which is not categorized but is having the `Show twsitie when row is expandalbe` property check and it also is listing some documents.

Column formula:

```
@If (Form = "fmProiect";
 "P: " + txt_Proiect;
Form = "fmDocCRM";
txt_Subiect;
"" )
```

I'm trying to achieve the same thing in a view panel - having the above view as Data Source Domino View.
I tried to add some icons for the expand/collapse property:

```
<xp:viewColumn columnName="$6" id="viewColumn3"
            collapsedImage="/2.png" expandedImage="/1.png">
```

But still the column isn't categorized. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the attribute `indentResponses="true"` to your xp:viewColumn. Then *response* documents can by collapsed and expanded.

Note: As you described in your question, you have in Notes Client view the column not categorized but you can make visible or hide documents behind a document in view. Those documents are "[response documents](http://techlab.ytria.com/2247/ibm-lotus-notes-secrets/dealing-lotus-notes-parentresponse-issues/)". They have an internal item "$REF" with the document id of the parent.

Comment: Indeed, in notes client the respective form was Response type. Should I declared also in xpages the same type for the respective form? ( which now plays the role of a deposit ) I've added the indentResponses="true", and I've added some icons for the expand/collapse properties. Still, the column has no twistie in xpages

Comment: My code for xp:viewColumn: <xp:viewColumn columnName="$6" id="viewColumn2"
   indentResponses="true" displayAs="link" showCheckbox="true"
   collapsedImage="/2.png" expandedImage="/1.png">
   <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Document"
    id="viewColumnHeader2">
   </xp:viewColumnHeader>
  </xp:viewColumn>

Comment: The twistiest show only up if a document has response documents. So, yes, you have to create response documents in XPages too. You can use the event Action "Create Response Document".

Comment: Definetely, I'm missing something: for the parent ID, I will use the $REF parameter or I must use some computed javascript code to take the parent ID ?

Comment: The documents have to be created as response documents already. You can't "fix" it in the view. So, you have to care that the response documents have the $REF field set - e.g. during creating with event Action "Create Response Document"

Comment: <xp:createResponse name="/xDocument_nou.xsp"
        parentId="#{javascript:docProiect.getParentId()}">
       </xp:createResponse>

Comment: for the response form / custom control should I use ignoreRequestParams = "true" & specify also the parentID in the properties ?

Comment: Use `docProiect.getDocument().getUniversalID()` for parentId.

Comment: It works. thank you. I still have some doubts if I should use ignoreRequestParams="true" property for the response doc.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use ignoreRequestParams="true" in xDocument_nou.xsp's data source.